# SoundPool issue on Android 11

Tags: android, soundpool

It seems that soundPool Api is not working correctly on android 11. I hear the sound like slow motion. Have anyone any related issue ?

My code

```
 private SoundPool soundPool;
 private int wonSound;

...

 soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder().setMaxStreams(1).build();
 wonSound = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.slot_win_1, 1);

...

 soundPool.play(wonSound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool#play(int,%20float,%20float,%20int,%20int,%20float)?

SoundPool's function play() takes as its last parameter:

> float: playback rate (1.0 = normal playback, range 0.5 to 2.0)

So, playback rates below 1 will sound slower than the original sound. To play your sound in its original playback rate, you should call play() like this:

```
soundPool.play(wonSound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
```